# Sort object contents by a reference array

Tags: php, sorting

My question may look a little silly but I'm writing an object that outputs HTML tables from given data. The given data is a json-encoded string which contains these a header array and a data object:

for example:

```
{
    "header":["id","fname","lname","position"],
    "data":{
        "0":{"position":"Developer","fname":"Tom","lname":"Jones","id":12},
        "1":{"position":"UI Designer","fname":"John","lname":"Smith","id":18},
        "2":{"position":"UX Specialist","fname":"Farid","lname":"Rn","id":110}
    }
}
```

The problem is that the data's ordering is not the same as the header.

I want to use the header array as reference and sort each rows of data object by it. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure!  Use an external and internal loop. The external loop runs through data elements, and the internal loop runs through the header list.  For each item in the header list, get it's value from the associative array in the data item.

Psuedocode:

```
foreach ($thing->data as $item) {
    // here would be a good place for the <tr>
    foreach ($thing->header as $header) {
        $dataforheader = $item->$header;
        // do something, maybe output a <td>
    }
}
```

Now, you could also put this into an alternate data structure for sorting.

Comment: Thanks but I can't make it work. BTW items are objects not arrays. only the header is an array.

Comment: I would work to make the data item an associative array, such that you could do this: $thingy.data[0]["position"] and get "Developer".  This allows you to use the header string as the associative argument to the array.

Comment: It should become `$item->$header;`

Comment: Ah.  Well, my PHP is rusty, but we often do similar things in Java.  Glad you worked it out.

Comment: I changed your code a little bit, I hope you don't mind it ;)

Comment: Don't mind at all.. will now be easier for others searching for similar answers.